# WiX toolset execute custom action after installation and wait for completion

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.10

I want to execute my .exe file, which displays `MessageBox` and exits upon clicking OK. `CustomAction` should be executed after installation is finished, but before displaying `Finish` dialog. Problem is, that I'm not able to set main installer window to wait for clicking on OK button (`Finish` dialog is displayed directly, therefore main window can be completely closed without clicking OK button).
WiX Toolset version: v3.10

Product source code:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#ExeId]" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchExe" After="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<CustomAction Id="LaunchExe" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="yes" />
```

Component source code:

```
<Component Id="ExeId" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Guid="*">
  <File Id="ExeId" Source=".\ExeName.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
</Component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I mannaged to run it. Resulting code is:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchExe" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
<CustomAction Id="LaunchExe" FileKey="ExeId" ExeCommand="" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
```

Note that `NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE` condition had to be added, because windows was not able to uninstall the application.